# ActiveX error on changing inner parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, activex

I'm working with ActiveX this way :

```
this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1 = new AxBacs_DBTableRepProj1.AxBacs_DBTableRepX();

((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1)).BeginInit();
// 
// My ActiveX
// 
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FRIIB));
    this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1.Location           = new System.Drawing.Point(157, 172);
    this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1.Name               = "axBacs_DBTableRepX1";
    this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1.OcxState           = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axBacs_DBTableRepX1.OcxState")));
    this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1.Dock               = DockStyle.Fill; 
    this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1.TabIndex           = 0;

    // INNER PARAMETER CAUSING ERROR AND DOESN'T WORK
    //this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1.ax_DSN             = "odbcsql"

((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1)).EndInit();

this.Analize.Controls.Add(this.axBacs_DBTableRepX1);
```

But when I try to change some ActiveX parameter I've got crash with error :

```
Exception of type 'System.Windows.Forms.AxHost+InvalidActiveXStateException' was thrown.
```

And stack trace ... nothing special :

```
   at AxBacs_DBTableRepProj1.AxBacs_DBTableRepX.set_ax_DSN(String value)
   at friib.FRIIB.FRIIB_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Nemerle\WTP\friib\friib\FRIIB.cs:line 67
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at friib.Program.Main() in D:\Nemerle\WTP\friib\friib\Program.cs:line 15
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

How can I work with my ActiveX ? Maybe I need something addition to change it's parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to put the control on the form in the constructor.  That way the ActiveX control is properly initialized by the time the Load event runs.  You can probably fix this right now by moving the ax_DSN property assignment *after* the Controls.Add() call.

Note that the OcxState assignment is going to break sooner or later as well, you cannot leave it the way it is.  Looks to me you originally had this control placed on the form with the designer, then moved the code out of InitializeComponent().  Avoid that, it causes more trouble then it solves.

Comment: Yes it helped , I even removed it from Form_Load to some button ... maybe I can put it in some other place ? Something after form_Load. After all I can't add it to designer because it crushes whole project and Visual Studio . . . I really tried so.